# Jenkins in Windows shows UI in russian language

Tags: jenkins

I am from Ukraine.
When I open Jenkins in the browser I see all the UI in Russian.
I am running Jenkins on Windows.

However - there is no Russian in Windows configuration "Region and Settings".
Format - English(United States).
Location - United States.
Only the Timezone is Ukrainian - UTC +02:00.

Is it possible to force Jenkins to show the UI in English language?

PS.
I did not have such a problem with Hudson before.

[Locale Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Locale+Plugin) helped to change the default locale to English.

I changed the language in the configuration of Chrome and now Jenkins is in English :)

Comment: Hi, good to know it solved your problem, but it's clearer if you write the solution as an answer to your question.

Comment: The setting is located on the `/configure` url of your system (after you restart Jenkins)

Answer (score 141):

By default, Jenkins uses the default language of your browser, if it is set. To change it, you could do the follow.

**1. Download and install the locale plugin:**

1. From the main page of Jenkins, go to Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins
2. Click on Availables
3. Check the "Locale plugin" and clicks on "Download now and install after restart".

*Jenkins will download the plugin and restart if not job has been scheduled.*

**2. Set the language:**

*Once the plugin has been installed, change the language using following steps:*

1. From the main page of Jenkins, go to Manage Jenkins -> Configure System.
2. Under Locale, there will be a field called "Default Language". Enter the new language. It could be "en" or "ENGLISH".
3. Under the text box, check the checkBox called "Ignore browser preference and force this language to all users".

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I needed it.

Answer (score 25):

[Locale Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Locale+Plugin) helped to change default locale to en.

Answer (score 21):

A better and more simple solution is to just remove Russian from Chrome.

In other words, change Browser Language Settings.

e.g. for Chrome, Go to Chrome Settings -> Language -> Remove selected language.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.

Comment: Go to Chrome Settings - > Language - > Remove selected language. In this case, it's should be Russian.

Comment: This is the easier and better solution. Set Browser Language preference. Jenkins will use that. Using the locale plugin you can change default language or override browser language settings for all users which might not be the right thing to do.

Comment: good solution in case one cannot restart Jenkins after install the language plugin. thanks!

Comment: thank you I was looking for this solution for so long and did not know ehre to find this settings in chrome!

Answer (score 9):

[image]

You have to install the Locale plugin, which is already available but not installed as default, and then under Manage System > Locale insert "Locale.ENGLISH" in java style.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can try this

`$ sudo languagesetup`

and choose `1) Use English for the main language` to change it back.

Reference,
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202036

Answer (score 4):

By default, Jenkins takes your browser language. To change it, you need to install [Locale](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Locale+Plugin) plugin and set proper language to ignore browser preferences. Go to Manage Jenkins -> Configure System, find Default Language and set what you need.
You can check the video https://youtu.be/UiikMY1uW1w

Answer (score 3):

Seems like chrome has an issue on this,
It kept sending Hebrew as the first option in the
`Accept-Language` on the header
although English was set to be the top-language on the list (Chrome settings > Languages)

**Solution**
And only after I've added some other language (Russian for instance) and set it to be the 'top' and then set the English back to be the 'top' it solved!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is change your browser's language settings and put english first.

Answer (score 0):

My operating system is windows 10. I want to use English languages for Jenkins UI. 
For Region & Languages, I added Turkish and English my default setting is English, however, Jenkins UI is Turkish. If I remove Turkish Jenkins UI looks fine and it turns on English.

[image: Region & Languages]

Answer (score 0):

My solution is pretty simple: use an extension in Chromium compatible browsers like this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locale-switcher/kngfjpghaokedippaapkfihdlmmlafcc, that lets you change the locale of the browser easily.

This solution works not only for Jenkins, but for many other websites, and doesn't require to restart Jenkins.

You can test the web with differents languages.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Change language in Chrome to change automatic language in Jenkins.