# Jenkins 2.153 in Chrome 71 (set to English) on Windows 7 shows partly non-English - how to force English?

Tags: user-interface, jenkins

Everywhere I've read it said jenkins honors browser language, like here [Jenkins in Windows shows UI in russian language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350707/jenkins-in-windows-shows-ui-in-russian-language).

I saw non-English interface of Jenkins in Chrome and set Chrome to English (now Chrome menus are in English) - still non-English.
I cleared cookies and stored websites data - still non-English.
I checked `jenkins/pluginManager/installed` and have not found `Locale`, so Jenkins cannot be forced to specific language - or it can be other way?

Any ideas why I still see what I see?

If you would advice to check some settings, please write where and how to find them (like should be between such and such, should look such and such), as they can be named differently in non-fully-English interface.

Answer (score 0):

As I've found via inspect (right-click page in chrome), browser sends accept-language in request header as still non-English with highest weight even after I deleted other languages in chrome settings. Problem lies in chrome, not jenkins.